# MySQL SELECT starts with data from another table?

Tags: mysql, select

Can anyone help me with a MySQL query I'm trying to put together.  I have two tables as follows (cut down just for the example).

```
uk_postcodes
____________
Pcode | County        | Region
AB10  | Aberdeen      | Scotland
AB11  | Aberdeen      | Scotland
B10   | West Midlands | West Midlands

p_venues
________
id | Venue_name     | address_postcode
1  | Samples venue  | AB10 1AT
2  | Samples venue  | B10 2DZ
```

Quite simply, I'm trying to select the `Region` from table `uk_postcodes` based on the corresponding postcode (`address_postcode`) in the `p_venues` table.

I've tried `Like%` and `REGEXP ^` but can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I've tried...

```
SELECT * FROM `uk_postcodes`, `p_venues` 
WHERE `p_venues`.address_postcode REGEXP ^ `uk_postcodes`.Pcode
```

This would be easy if I could specifically supply data hardcoded but the problem lies with the comparison (`uk_postcodes.Pcode`) in the 2nd part of the query being a field - I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Can anyone please help??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to do it. You need to concatenate the `LIKE` wildcard to the Pcode value from uk_postcodes. If any of your columns are fixed length text, you may need to trim trailing spaces first.

```
SELECT  p.*, u.Region
FROM    p_venues p
        INNER JOIN
                uk_postcodes u
                ON p.address_postcode LIKE CONCAT(u.Pcode, '%')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - in theory I see how this works but again I''m running into problems with the wildcard part.  The above works if I remove the + '%'.   As soon as I add this on it throws a syntax error?

Comment: When you say it works without, do you get the regions you expect, or does it just run without error? What is the syntax error you're getting?

Comment: If I remove the +'%' part it displays the correct regions as expected if the `address_postcode` value is exactly the same as `Pcode` - so,  AB10 would pull the correct region, AB10 1BT would not. Hence the wildcard %  but it's this part that isn't working.

Comment: This is the error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ '%'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join the tables. Table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.col = t2.col